# DKIM error: dkim=neutral (bad version) header.i=

Tags: centos, postfix, spam, dkim

Ive been struggling the last couple of hours with setting up DKIM on my Postfix/CentOS 5.3 server.

It finally sends and signs the emails, but apparently Google still does not like it. The errors I'm getting are:

> dkim=neutral (bad version)
>   header.i=@mydomain.com.au

from googles "show original" interface.

This is what my DKIM-signature header look like:

> v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=simple/simple;
>   d=mydomain.com.au; s=default;
>   t=1267326852;
>   bh=0wHpkjkf7ZEiP2VZXAse+46PC1c=;
>   h=Date:From:Message-Id:To:Subject;
>   b=IFBaqfXmFjEojWXI/WQk4OzqglNjBWYk3jlFC8sHLLRAcADj6ScX3bzd+No7zos6i
>   KppG9ifwYmvrudgEF+n1VviBnel7vcVT6dg5cxOTu7y31kUApR59dRU5nPR/to0E9l
>   dXMaBoYPG8edyiM+soXo7rYNtlzk+0wd5glgFP1I=

Very appreciative of any suggestions as to how I can solve this problem!

Btw, here is exactly how I installed dkim-milter in CentOS 5.3 for postfix, if anyone is interested (based on [this guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/set-up-dkim-for-multiple-domains-on-postfix-with-dkim-milter-2.8.x-centos-5.3)):

```
mkdir dkim-milter
cd dkim-milter

wget http://www.topdog-software.com/oss/dkim-milter/dkim-milter-2.8.3-1.x86_64.rpm
======S======
Newest version: http://www.topdog-software.com/oss/dkim-milter/
======E======

rpm -Uvh dkim-milter-2.8.3-1.x86_64.rpm
/usr/bin/dkim-genkey -r -d mydomain.com.au

======S======
add contents of default.txt to DNS as TXT
_ssp._domainkey TXT dkim=unknown
_adsp._domainkey TXT dkim=unknown
default._domainkey TXT v=DKIM1; g=*; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GWETBNiQKBgQC5KT1eN2lqCRQGDX+20I4liM2mktrtjWkV6mW9WX7q46cZAYgNrus53vgfl2z1Y/95mBv6Bx9WOS56OAVBQw62+ksXPT5cRUAUN9GkENPdOoPdpvrU1KdAMW5c3zmGOvEOa4jAlB4/wYTV5RkLq/1XLxXfTKNy58v+CKETLQS/eQIDAQAB
======E======

mv default.private default
mkdir /etc/mail/dkim/keys/mydomain.com.au
mv default /etc/mail/dkim/keys/mydomain.com.au
chmod 600 /etc/mail/dkim/keys/mydomain.com.au/default
chown dkim-milt.dkim-milt /etc/mail/dkim/keys/mydomain.com.au/default

vim /etc/dkim-filter.conf
======S======
ADSPDiscard             yes
ADSPNoSuchDomain        yes
AllowSHA1Only           no
AlwaysAddARHeader       no
AutoRestart             yes
AutoRestartRate         10/1h
BaseDirectory           /var/run/dkim-milter
Canonicalization        simple/simple
Domain                  mydomain.com.au #add all your domains here and seperate them with comma
ExternalIgnoreList      /etc/mail/dkim/trusted-hosts
InternalHosts           /etc/mail/dkim/trusted-hosts
KeyList                 /etc/mail/dkim/keylist
LocalADSP               /etc/mail/dkim/local-adsp-rules
Mode                    sv
MTA                     MSA
On-Default              reject
On-BadSignature         reject
On-DNSError             tempfail
On-InternalError        accept
On-NoSignature          accept
On-Security             discard
PidFile                 /var/run/dkim-milter/dkim-milter.pid
QueryCache              yes
RemoveOldSignatures     yes
Selector                default
SignatureAlgorithm      rsa-sha1
Socket                  inet:20209@localhost
Syslog                  yes
SyslogSuccess           yes
TemporaryDirectory      /var/tmp
UMask                   022
UserID                  dkim-milt:dkim-milt
X-Header                yes
======E======

vim /etc/mail/dkim/keylist
======S======
*@mydomain.com.au:mydomain.com.au:/etc/mail/dkim/keys/mydomain.com.au/default
======E======

vim /etc/postfix/main.cf
======S====== Add:
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:20209
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:20209
milter_protocol = 2
milter_default_action = accept
======E======

vim /etc/mail/dkim/trusted-hosts
======S======
localhost
127.0.0.1
======E======

/etc/mail/local-host-names
======S======
localhost
127.0.0.1
======E======

/sbin/chkconfig dkim-milter on
/etc/init.d/dkim-milter start
/etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution: Turns out I missed that my DNS host automatically makes all entries into lower case (for reasons unknown to anyone but themselves). This means the "v=DKIM1" turned into "v=dkim1" which is an invalid version. It also means it turned by base64 hash into all lower case, thus breaking it.

Now getting in contact with my host to make them change their system. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Let me guess.. GoDaddy? :D

Answer (score 0):

This problem is at least not related to your penguin box, leave it alone.

Start with where you manage DNS entries and:

- Make sure you REMOVE all previous DKIM entries, even if they "look"
  the same..
- Save Your Zone, make sure entries deleted.
- Add your (*proper/new/old/verified*) DKIM signature line again ..
- Double check the *t=y* part in there..
- Save Zone File
- Check CapitAliZatioN of the DKIM line..and again please!

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In case you're running Exim, the solution might be to edit `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf` and set

`DKIM_CANON = simple`

In case the setting is `relaxed` Exim may apply changes to message that cause problems for DKIM validation.

(I haven't seen this problem myself, this is just a rewrite of the old answer by @byiior based on historical content from Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20131106173526/http://joyit.ru/administrirovanie/36-exim-dkim-dkim-neutral-bad-version-header-i.html)

Answer (score -1):

dkim=neutral (bad version) header.iI have same problem, an answer here https://web.archive.org/web/20130922221826/http://joyit.ru:80/home/36-exim-dkim-dkim-neutral-bad-version-header-i.html . You need to add DKIM_CANON

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.